# Navigation without Component.js?

Tags: hash, routes, navigation, sapui5

I need to know -  [HashChanger](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.routing.HashChanger.html) and [Router](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.routing.Router.html) concept without Component.js as I am not able to find in [SAPUI5 SDK - Developers Guide](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/99ac68a5b1c3416ab5c84c99fefa250d.html).

Can someone provide a simple example where one can navigate to another page by changing the Hash?

~Rahul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The routing concepts are very well explained in the SAPUI walk-through tutorial: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/e5200ee755f344c8aef8efcbab3308fb.html

A good and simple example can be found in the UI5 explored app:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.ui.core.routing.Router/samples

To launch the example in a separate page to see the hash portions in your browser, you could use this link:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/ui/core/demokit/sample/RoutingFullscreen/RoutingFullscreen.html

Comment: Thanks jpenninkhof!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the example given in the documentation you have linked?
I have copied and expanded it a little:

```js
var router = new Router(
// Routes
[
    {
        // no view creation related properties are in the route
        name: "startRoute",
        //no hash
        pattern: "",
        // you can find this target in the targetConfig
        target: "welcome"
    },
    {
        // no view creation related properties are in the route
        name: "productRoute",
        //no hash
        pattern: "product/{productId}",
        // you can find this target in the targetConfig
        target: "productTarget"
    }
],
// Default values shared by routes and Targets
{
    viewNamespace: "my.application.namespace",
    viewType: "XML"
},
// You should only use this constructor when you are not using a router with a component.
// Please use the metadata of a component to define your routes and targets.
// The documentation can be found here: sap.ui.core.UIComponent#.extend.
null,
// Target config
{
     //same name as in the route called 'startRoute'
     welcome: {
         // All properties for creating and placing a view go here or in the config
         viewName: "Welcome",
         controlId: "app",
         controlAggregation: "pages"
     },
     productTarget: {
         // All properties for creating and placing a view go here or in the config
         viewName: "Product",
         controlId: "app",
         controlAggregation: "pages"
     }
});

// You can navigate to a route programmatically too.
// This is the same as entering the url ...index.html#product/P12345 in your browser window.
router.navTo("productRoute",{productId: "P12345"});
```